# Find a record and its neighbour in an ordered query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I have a list of users. Each user has a score. I'd like to query my database to get a list of 11 users, ordered by score, and centered on a specific record (i'd like the 5 previous records, my queried record, and the 5 following records).

So for example, assuming the following table:

```
Id  Name      Score 
1   Albert    12
2   Bernard   85
3   Christian 98
4   Danielle  5
5   Emilie    65
6   Fabrice   34
7   Gaston    123
8   Hasting   76
9   Isidor    90
10  Jacques   3
11  Kellam    32
12  Lily      13
13  Mael      4242
```

If I run my query using Emily as a pivot, I should get the following:

```
5   Danielle  --- -5
12  Albert    --- -4
13  Lily      --- -3
32  Kellam    --- -2
34  Fabrice   --- -1
65  Emilie    ---  0 (pivot)
76  Hasting   --- +1
85  Bernard   --- +2
90  Isidor    --- +3
98  Christian --- +4
123 Gaston    --- +5
```

(notice how Jacques and Mael haven't been returned, because they're not in the requested range)

How can I achieve this result by only using a minimal amount of queries and/or only simple queries?

I'm using **Postgres**, but I'd like something that could also work on **SQLite**

Comment: Please tell us what RDBMS you are using, because there are some subtle syntax differences.

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm using Postgres, but I'd like something that could also work on SQLite - my tests are using it as an in-memory replacement for postgres.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE, find exactly `5 before` and `5 after` emilie**

- [SQLite version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/70601/1)
- [PostgreSQL version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70601/3)
- [MySQL SQL Fiddle :](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7c76e/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE u
    (`Id` int, `Name` varchar(9), `Score` int)
;

INSERT INTO u
    (`Id`, `Name`, `Score`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Albert', 12),
    (2, 'Bernard', 85),
    (3, 'Christian', 98),
    (4, 'Danielle', 5),
    (5, 'Emilie', 65),
    (6, 'Fabrice', 34),
    (7, 'Gaston', 123),
    (8, 'Hasting', 76),
    (9, 'Isidor', 90),
    (10, 'Jacques', 3),
    (11, 'Kellam', 32),
    (12, 'Lily', 13),
    (13, 'Mael', 4242),
    (14, 'a', 65),
    (15, 'b', 65),
    (16, 'c', 65),
    (17, 'd', 65)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM u
      WHERE 
        Score >= (
          SELECT Score
          FROM u
          WHERE Name = 'Emilie'
        )
        AND Name != 'Emilie'
      ORDER BY Score ASC
      LIMIT 5
    ) a
    ORDER BY a.Score DESC
  ) z
UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM u
  WHERE Name = 'Emilie'
UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM u
    WHERE 
      Score < (
        SELECT Score
        FROM u
        WHERE Name = 'Emilie'
      )
    ORDER BY Score DESC
    LIMIT 5
  ) w
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7c76e/2/0)**:

```
| Id |     Name | Score |
|----|----------|-------|
|  8 |  Hasting |    76 |
| 16 |        c |    65 |
| 15 |        b |    65 |
| 17 |        d |    65 |
| 14 |        a |    65 |
|  5 |   Emilie |    65 |
|  6 |  Fabrice |    34 |
| 11 |   Kellam |    32 |
| 12 |     Lily |    13 |
|  1 |   Albert |    12 |
|  4 | Danielle |     5 |
```

Comment: Simplified: `select * from
((select * from users where score >= 65 limit 5)
union all
(select * from users where score < 65 limit 4))
a order by score;`

Comment: well, my answer was simpler, but the truth remains that it was structurally identical to yours, so I deleted it.

Comment: @MikeNakis oh thank, wasn’t expecting that. so yes, you use fixed value, but as it seem OP want "around user" I put the sub-query for it. The point is for my query, I don't show 12 result if I have someone with same score as Emilie (as they are over and under at the same time). So I'll add a note as I don't know what op want...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when multiple users have the same score: you can see that in such a case, the results won't be centered on Emilie (she will be in the third position from the start, instead of the sixth). It might be a pretty big issue, since Emilie might be pushed out of the final result (cf [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d4cf/1/0))

Comment: @MaëlNison ok done, take a look, but it's a big query that use many temp table, so not a good solution I think...

Comment: @MaëlNison and I add the PostgreSQL and the SQLite version too

Answer (score 0):

`Sql Server/Postgresql/Oracle` you can use windowed function:

```
WITH cte(Score, Name, rn) AS
(
  SELECT Score, Name, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score) AS rn
  FROM tab
)
SELECT Score, Name, rn - (SELECT rn FROM cte WHERE Name = 'Emilie')
FROM cte
WHERE ABS(rn - (SELECT rn FROM cte WHERE Name = 'Emilie')) <=5
ORDER BY Score
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/403890)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦══════╗
║ Score ║   Name    ║ Rank ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬══════╣
║     5 ║ Danielle  ║   -5 ║
║    12 ║ Albert    ║   -4 ║
║    13 ║ Lily      ║   -3 ║
║    32 ║ Kellam    ║   -2 ║
║    34 ║ Fabrice   ║   -1 ║
║    65 ║ Emilie    ║    0 ║
║    76 ║ Hasting   ║    1 ║
║    85 ║ Bernard   ║    2 ║
║    90 ║ Isidor    ║    3 ║
║    98 ║ Christian ║    4 ║
║   123 ║ Gaston    ║    5 ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩══════╝
```

I've assumed that name is unique. If not you may need to use `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` in subquery. The better way to do it is to use `(SELECT rn FROM cte WHERE id = 5)` because `Id` is unique.

If the score values can be the same you can change `ROW_NUMBER()` to `DENSE_RANK()`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this generalizable SQL solution without window functions which should be compliant across most RDMS's.

You will need to manually or dynamically pass the person of the pivot. A parameterized query with general purpose coding (VBA, PHP, Python, Java, C#, etc.) or a stored procedure can handle that:

```
SELECT [Name], [Score], [rank]
FROM (
     SELECT t1.[Name], t1.[Score],
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM [pivotTable] t2
            WHERE t2.[Score] >= (SELECT t3.[Score] FROM [pivotTable] t3 
                                 WHERE t3.[Name]='Emilie')) -
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM [pivotTable] t2
            WHERE t1.[Score] <= t2.[Score]) As rank
     FROM [pivotTable] t1
     ) AS derivedTbl
WHERE [rank] >= -5 AND [rank] <= 5
ORDER BY [Score]
```

Comment: This is **not** ANSI SQL. And window functions **are** part of the ANSI SQL standard (have been for over 10 years).